# Register and Retrieving Multiple Connection String using Autofac on .net core

Tags: autofac

When I register 2 connection string on autofac, i only retrieve the last registered connection string using keyfilter on IDbConnection.

```
  //Register
   builder.RegisterType<OracleConnection>()
   .As(IDbConnection)....
   .Named<IDbConnection>("conn1")

  //Retrieve
  Public Repository([KeyFilter]IDbConnection connection)....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading this topic:

http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html

I just missed the .WithAttributeFiltering() when registering my component with the filter so the container knows to look for it.